# Simpy time event not properly sorted

Tags: python, sorting, networking, simulation, simpy

I'm trying to simulate a network queue using simpy library it works fine when I set the arrival rate and service are at 1sec (randomly generated exponetial dist with mean 1). However, when i set the arrival rate at 9x faster than the service rate(ie. arrival = 9pkts per sec, service rate = 1 pkt per sec), the simpy process are not printing it properly (in timely order)

example:

```
packet0 1219 arriving at 0.000000    
packet1 3568 arriving at 0.150441
packet2 3194 arriving at 0.300072
packet3 783 arriving at 0.303343
packet4 1308 arriving at 0.622341
packet5 150 arriving at 0.879188
packet6 353 arriving at 0.949535
packet7 1066 arriving at 1.036728
packet8 305 arriving at 1.038195
**packet0 1219 depart at 1.585690**
**packet1 3568 depart at 3.644606**
**packet9 3101 arriving at 1.074615**
packet10 217 arriving at 1.235867
packet11 186 arriving at 1.413119
packet12 169 arriving at 1.519886
packet2 3194 depart at 4.864265
packet13 2563 arriving at 1.520083
```

Notice that in between the ** **, the process are not printed within the timeline. Any workaround for this? Thanks.

edited to include code:

```
NEW_CUSTOMERS = 100  # Total number of customers
INTERVAL_CUSTOMERS = 0.111111  # Generate new customers roughly every x         seconds
SIZE = 1250

def source(env, number, interval, port):
    """Source generates customers randomly"""
    for i in range(number):
        size =  int(random.expovariate(0.0008))
        packet = Packet(env, '%d' % i, size, port, time_in_port=1)
        env.process(packet)
        t = random.expovariate(1 / interval)
        yield env.timeout(t)

def Packet(env, id, size, port, time_in_port):
    arrive = env.now
    yield Queue.buffer.put(size)
    print('packet%s %s arriving at %lf' % (id, size, arrive))

    with port.request() as req:
        yield req

        tip = random.expovariate(1/time_in_port)
        yield env.timeout(tip)
        amount = size
        yield Queue.buffer.get(amount)
        print('packet%s %s depart at %lf' % (id, size, env.now))

class queue:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.buffer = simpy.Container(env, init = 0, capacity=12500)

random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
env = simpy.Environment()
Queue = queue(env)

# Start processes and run
port = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
env.process(source(env, NEW_CUSTOMERS, INTERVAL_CUSTOMERS, port))
env.run()
```

Comment: It looks like the times you report in the "depart" messages show the elapsed time to service the packet and not the time of departure. But it's very hard to say because you are asking us to help you debug code we can't see.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've included the code.